# Javascript - setting background image for an element by its value

Tags: javascript, ajax

THIS CODE IS just php to fetch online players data :

```
printf( "<div class=\"online\"><b class=\"Race\"> %s </b><b class=\"PlayerName\"> %s </b><b class=\"PPID\"> %s </b><br><li class=\"Class\"> %s </li><b class=\"Role\"> %s </b><b class=\"Gender\"> %s </b></div>",$row["Race"], $row["PlayerName"], $row["PPID"], $row["Class"], $row["Role"], $row["Gender"]);
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

No need to focus on above code the result is going to be this:

the result i want when the above code get fetched from the database:

**what i need is the image set**

PLAYERNAME : JOHN

CLASS: WARRIOR <--(attached picture "standard warrior picture")

RACE: HUMAN <--(attached picture "standard human picture")

So that all online humans get same picture... all warriors have same picture when they show up online on the webpage.

**FOR EXAMPLE :** two players shows up

```
<b class="Race"> Human </b>
<b class="Class"> Warrior </b>
<b class="Race"> Elf </b>
<b class="Class"> Warrior </b>
```

if i use `document.getElementByClassName("Race").style.backgroundImage = "url('human.png')"` 
**this will choose all races Human and Elf while i want image for elves too . 
Is there is anyway that i can set the style for the keyword or the value of the element itself.**

I would appreciate any help thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not showing enough code... Show us what you have tried so far. My guess is that you just need CSS though.

Comment: well yea but through a javascript. let me explain what i need again.

Comment: Can you provide some more of the DOM maybe a complete class="online" div

Comment: check the first code its data fetched using ajax to the main site which has body with other elements. so its <div id=online><b>warrior</b> and so on only div online has the online data of the player. also the onload function won't work since loading the online data to the page takes 2 sec to get online players

Answer (score 0):

Although Javascript is certainly not the best tool for the job, you could use the `innerHTML` property to do what you want.

```
document.getElementByClassName("Race").forEach(function(dom){
    if(dom.innerHTML.indexOf('Human')>=0){
        dom.style.backgroundImage = "url('human.png')";
    }else if(dom.innerHTML.indexOf('Elf')>=0){
        dom.style.backgroundImage = "url('elf.png')";
    }
});
```

I'd like to insist on the fact that you could easily change the HTML you produce, and then use a VERY fast and easy CSS styling to do the job:

```
<b class="Race Human"> Human </b>
<b class="Class Warrior "> Warrior </b>
<b class="Race Elf"> Elf </b>
<b class="Class Warrior "> Warrior </b>

.Race.Human{
   background-image:url('human.png');
}
.Race.Elf{
   background-image:url('elf.png');
}
```

Note that the CSS version will NOT require you to rerun scripts when players are added or something. While the javascript version will need to be triggered every time a dom element is added.